# How to check all strings in a list?

Tags: python, string, urllib2

```
website = str(raw_input('Website: '))
palavras_chaves = ['joomla', 'Joomla']
palavras_chaves2 = ['wordpress', 'Wordpress', 'WordPress', 'wp']    
abrindo = urllib2.urlopen(website)
abrindo = abrindo.read()
if palavras_chaves[0] and palavras_chaves[1] in abrindo:
    print '\nÉ um joomla!'

elif palavras_chaves2[0] and palavras_chaves2[1] and palavras_chaves2[2] and palavras_chaves2[3] in abrindo:        
    print '\nÉ um wordpress!'

else:
    print '\nÉ um CMS desconhecido!'
```

I want to know how to check all strings without specifies it. Seems to be very simple but I tried everything that came to my mind and didn't work it.

Comment: Note that the following is interpreted like so (grouping added): `if (palavras_chaves[0]) and (palavras_chaves[1] in abrindo):`.  The non-empty string `palavras_chaves[0]` is always `True` so this would pass if only the 2nd word was in abrindo.  the correct (but long) way `if palavras_chaves[0] in abrindo and palavras_chaves[1] in abrindo:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @fourtheye points out, you need the built-in [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function here and you can utilize it with a list comprehension to do the job as depicted below.

So Try this:

```
if all(i in abrindo for i in palavras_chaves):
    print '\nÉ um joomla!'

elif all(i in abrindo for i in palavras_chaves2):
    print '\nÉ um wordpress!'
else:
    print '\nÉ um CMS desconhecido!'
```

## EDIT:

I think if you do it manually like:

```
if palavras_chaves[0] and palavras_chaves[1] in abrindo:
```

It works because `palavras_chaves[1]` is in `abrindo` however `palavras_chaves[0]` might not be in `abrindo` but when you use `all()` all strings in `palavras_chaves` **have** to be in `abrindo` and just in case if one string is not in `abrindo`, ***It fails!***

See this example, your trying to do something like this, and you'd expect it to return `'Works as expected'` however it returns the opposite

```
>>> if 'Hey' and 'Bye' in 'Bye':
...     print 'Not expected right?'
... else:
...     print 'Works as expected'
...     
#Not expected right?
```

But using `all()`:

```
if all(i in 'Bye'for i in ['Hey','Bye']):
    print 'Not expected right?'
else:
    print 'Works as expected'
#Works as expected
```

Comment: Any website. Seems that "if" and "elif" isn't checked, it's directly jumped to "else"

Comment: I got it, well, I'll let specifying it so but looks very repetitive x)!

Comment: Simplify to `if all(i in abrindo for i in palavras_chaves):`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I thought of being more explicit but thanks will edit

Answer (score -1):

Use python's built-in set, which have an issubset method. http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set